# unicode symbol size and shape changed in iOS

Tags: ios, unicode

I want to use **▾** – [BLACK DOWN-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/tryit.asp?deci=9662) in my app, but in reality, the triangle is misshaped and smaller than what is shown on the web browser. Is there a way to keep the size and the shape of this symbol(or unicode symbols in general) exactly the same in Xcode as what they are on the web browser?

[image]

Comment: Try with ▼  `BLACK DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE` or use attributed string to change font size for triangle

Comment: It could also be an issue with the font?

Comment: It wouldn't be an "issue" with the font, it would be just how the font is designed. Using exactly the same font as the website should help.